# Fast recursive grepping of svn working copy

Tags: windows, svn, bash, grep

I need to search all cpp/h files in svn working copy for "foo", excluding svn's special folders completely. What is the **exact** command for GNU grep?

Comment: As Frentos illustrates, your question would have been easily answered had you took the time to consult the man pages.

Comment: Hey freespace, why not just answer the "easy" question? I would gladly accept your answer if it's correct.

Answer (score 9):

I use [ack](http://petdance.com/ack/) for this purpose, it's like grep but automatically knows how to exclude source control directories (among other useful things).

Comment: Note that the ack package on Ubuntu/Debian is actually called "ack-grep", since there is a Kanji code converter called "ack".

Answer (score 7):

grep -ir --exclude-dir=.svn foo *

In the working directory will do.
Omit the 'i' if you want the search to be case sensitive.

If you want to check only .cpp and .h files use

grep -ir --include={*.cpp,*.h} --exclude-dir=.svn foo *

Comment: Any chance to replace * with something that only matches cpp/h?

Comment: Sorry, can't find --exclude-dir option: http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?grep

Comment: it's not available in all versions of grep. But on my ubuntu 8.04 system it's there at least

Answer (score 3):

Going a little off-topic:

If you have a working copy with a lot of untracked files (i.e. not version-controlled) and you **only** want to search source controlled files, you can do

```
svn ls -R | xargs -d '\n' grep <string-to-search-for>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a RTFM.  I typed 'man grep' and '/exclude' and got:

--exclude=GLOB
          Skip  files  whose  base  name  matches  GLOB  (using   wildcard
          matching).   A  file-name  glob  can  use  *,  ?,  and [...]  as
          wildcards, and \ to quote  a  wildcard  or  backslash  character
          literally.

--exclude-from=FILE
          Skip  files  whose  base name matches any of the file-name globs
          read from FILE  (using  wildcard  matching  as  described  under
          --exclude).

--exclude-dir=DIR
          Exclude  directories  matching  the  pattern  DIR from recursive
          searches.

Comment: RTFMing people is something you do on usenet. SO is different. By the way, you didn't answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote [this](http://www.soulsphere.org/tools/fuck-you-svn.sh) script which I've added to my .bashrc.  It automatically excludes SVN directories from grep, find and locate.

Comment: what about real find and locate?

Answer (score 1):

I use these bash aliases for grepping for content and files in svn trees... I find it faster and more pleasant to search from the commandline (and use `vim` for coding) rather than a GUI-based IDE:

```
s () {
    local PATTERN=$1
    local COLOR=$2
    shift; shift;
    local MOREFLAGS=$*

    if  ! test -n "$COLOR" ; then
        # is stdout connected to terminal?
        if test -t 1; then
            COLOR=always
        else
            COLOR=none
        fi
    fi

    find -L . \
        -not \( -name .svn -a -prune \) \
        -not \( -name templates_c -a -prune \) \
        -not \( -name log -a -prune \) \
        -not \( -name logs -a -prune \) \
        -type f \
        -not -name \*.swp \
        -not -name \*.swo \
        -not -name \*.obj \
        -not -name \*.map \
        -not -name access.log \
        -not -name \*.gif \
        -not -name \*.jpg \
        -not -name \*.png \
        -not -name \*.sql \
        -not -name \*.js \
        -exec grep -iIHn -E --color=${COLOR} ${MOREFLAGS} -e "${PATTERN}" \{\} \;
}

# s foo | less
sl () {
    local PATTERN=$*
    s "$PATTERN" always | less
}

# like s but only lists the files that match
smatch () {
    local PATTERN=$1
    s $PATTERN always -l
}

# recursive search (filenames) - find file
f () {
    find -L . -not \( -name .svn -a -prune \) \( -type f -or -type d \) -name "$1"
}
```